# PHPjasperxml don't show images in the pdf report

Tags: php, jasper-reports, laravel-5, export-to-pdf

I recently made pdf reports with phpjasperxml in a web application with php 5.5.9 and laravel 5.2.0.
I made the report in ireport 5.6.0 and it works perfectly.
but when I try to show the pdf report from the web application it does not show me the images that I put in the report.

composer.json

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.5.9",
            "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
            "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2.0",
            "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
            "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
            "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
            "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
            "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master",
            "laurentbrieu/tcpdf": "dev-master",
            "sergio-vilchis/laravel-phpjasperxml": "^1.0",
            "jaspersoft/rest-client": "v2.0.0"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/",
                "PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\": "src/PhpWord"
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/TestCase.php"
            ]
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "php artisan key:generate"
            ],
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
                "php artisan optimize"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
                "php artisan optimize"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "preferred-install": "dist"
        }
    }
```

Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ReportesRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use PHPJasperXML;
use Response;
class ReportesController extends Controller
{
public function Reporte_planilla_dieta_prof_noDocpdf($tipo) 
    {
        $parametros = explode(' ', $tipo); 
        $verdescar=$parametros[0];
        $mes=$parametros[1];
        $anio=$parametros[2];
        $server="localhost";
        $db="siarcaf";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";
        $version="0.8b";
        $pgport=5432;
        $pchartfolder="./class/pchart2"; 
//display errors should be off in the php.ini file
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);
//setting the path to the created jrxml file
$xml =simplexml_load_file("C:/xampp/htdocs/siarcaf/resources/views/Reportes/Reporte_planilla_dieta_prof_noDocpdf.jrxml");
$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
//$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
//dd($mes12);  
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("mes1"=>"'$mes'");
//dd($sql);
//$PHPJasperXML->sql = $sql;
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$dbdriver="mysql";
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db,$dbdriver);
//ob_end_clean();
//dd($PHPJasperXML);
if($verdescar==1)  //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file
        {
            $PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");
            //return Response::make($PHPJasperXML->outpage("I"));
        }
        if($verdescar==2)
        {
            $PHPJasperXML->outpage("D");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: image properties]

[image: report compiled]

[image: report from the webapp]

Comment: Show the jrxml path what you have used ?

Comment: What is your full image path ?

Comment: @JaimeFerminDonadoIraheta Are you passing image via parameter or you are using absolute or relative path for image?

Comment: <pageHeader>
  <band height="130" splitType="Stretch">
   <image>
    <reportElement x="229" y="10" width="95" height="107" uuid="b14034b4-0e72-4723-ba66-925d0ab2bf82"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\siarcaf\\public\\images\\Logo_UES.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
   </image>
  </band>
 </pageHeader>

Comment: i am using a absolute path for the image and i am grant permission to the windows folder

Answer (score 0):

PHPJasperXML require absolute base path of image in expression. you can pass expression by parameter or fields. your image path must be live var/www/html/SITE_FOLDER/IMAGE_PATH

and evaluation type must be string.